# offline chat storage using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a chat app using firebase, I want to store the chat data in the user device and show to the user if the internet is not available. 
I am torn between how to implement it I wanted to use realm but it increases app size almost by 6mb(my app size is 4mb), so I switched back to SQLite.

Now I want to know what would be the best practice to do so
I have implemented few processes still unclear how to do.

I have created a **master_chat** table in which I have `message_id`, `to` ,`from` and `thread_id` and secondary **chat_data** table where I used `message_id` as a reference to **master_chat** table and inserted `messageBody`, `toEmail`, `fromEmail`, `time`, `messageType`,`fileSize` ,`downloadLink`

now the question is should I follow this method so that everytime user enter the message it will be added to **chat_data** or directly store the *arrayList* and update it every time a message is sent or received.

any guidance will be great!

Comment: offtopic. don't you really think that 6mb is really so much memory?

Comment: @Vyacheslav it is, that's why I am using sqlite

Comment: nevertheless, that's your real problem? I just can create sql request.

Comment: @Vyacheslav my problem is what approach should I take for syncing with firebase

Comment: @rookieDeveloper have you check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities ? I think it will solve your problem

Comment: one line of code and its done @AtifFarrukh thanks

Comment: glad it worked for you :)

Comment: you want to store whole arraylist as a single row in sqlite right?

Comment: @dipali I wanted to, but `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
` did the trick

Comment: @rookieDeveloper you can store json string in sqlite database.you can convert arraylist to Json string.its better.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh can you please explain that `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` is providing only caching or offline storage?

Comment: @KrupaKakkad quoting from [Firebase document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) "By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database client would sync while online persists to disk and is available offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app."